# How to check if a variable is not empty in bash

Tags: bash, variables

I know, this question has been asked several times here but due to some reason whatsoever none of the answer mentioned before, didn't seem to work for me.

How can I check if the variable is not empty in bash, I tried the following methods but none of them worked:

```
if [ -z ${VAR+x} ]; then
    echo "VAR is not set"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z ${VAR+set} ]; then
    echo "VAR is not set"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z ${VAR} ]; then
    echo "VAR is not set"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z ${VAR// } ]; then
    echo "VAR is not set"
    exit 1
fi
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't work with `if [ -z ${VAR} ]` ?

Comment: "not set" is different from "empty". See the link above.

Comment: @hek2mgl With `[ -z  ${VAR} ]` it somehow assumes that the Var is set

Comment: @P.P. Lets assume that I am setting declaring the variable but setting it to an empty string, how will I evaluate then? In the answer it states to use `+set`, I tried it out but that doesn't work either

Comment: `[ -z "${VAR}" ]` is correct. If that doesn't work, then the problem is somewhere else.